# Parent POM is not flattened when deployed to Nexus

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci, nexus

I have a multi-module Maven project where the project `version` is set via the `revision` variable.

```
<groupId>pricing</groupId>
<artifactId>pricing-backend-pom</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <revision>3.0.7</revision>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>pricing-backend-war</module>
    <module>pricing-backend-model</module>
    <module>pricing-backend-client</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- flatten before deploy. removes $revision -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <!-- enable flattening -->
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>flatten</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <!-- ensure proper cleanup -->
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten.clean</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

During the Gitlab build, the project is deployed to a Nexus repository. Each module and the parent appear in Nexus but only the modules appear to be flattened. The module POMs each contain `<version>3.0.7</version>` but the parent POM still contains `<version>${revision}</version>`.

I find it difficult to understand why the parent is deployed differently to the modules. I have checked the build logs but cannot see any indication that the parent is handled in a different way.

The parent POM taken from Nexus:

```
<groupId>pricing</groupId>
<artifactId>pricing-backend-pom</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<properties>
    <revision>3.0.7</revision>
    ...
```

A module POM:

```
<groupId>pricing</groupId>
<artifactId>pricing-backend-client</artifactId>
<version>3.0.7</version>
<dependencies>
    ...
```

The build applies the required version:

```
$ echo New version= ${MAVEN_VERSION}
New version= -Drevision=3.0.7-SNAPSHOT
$ mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS ${MAVEN_VERSION} deploy -DskipTests
```

Answer (score 1):

The pom file to be installed can be explicitly set:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <pomFile>.flattened-pom.xml</pomFile>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Above, flatten-maven-plugin has been previously invoked to produce .flattened-pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you do a test by adding `-Drevision=<someVersion>` to the command line, does that produce correct results in Nexus?

I suspect it will.

Properties are interpolated very early in the process. When the command first runs, `${revision}` is undefined, so Maven leaves it as-is. The `flatten` then calculates `${revision}`, but that only applies from the time the plugin runs and later.

You can try researching "late binding" properties (they start with '@' instead of '$') but I'm not sure if those work in top level fields like the GAV coords.

Comment: The build works ok. The "problem" is the POM which appears in Nexus. (see question for details) The ${revision} is present in the parent POM <version> but properly resolved in the modules. :-/

Comment: I understand. I'm asking what ends up in Nexus if you run the normal process with `revision` defined on the command line as shown. Updated my post.

Comment: not sure if I understand you but I already set `revision` during the build. (I updated my question)

Comment: Thank you, that wasn't clear before. No idea what's happening then. You'll probably have to enable Maven debug logging (`-X`) and read the logs closely to see where things go awry.